# mutable variables racket for finding range

Tags: algorithm, functional-programming, scheme, racket

I am trying to solve this C question to find a function that takes in 2 integer parameters, a and b and produces the range of all the elements between them, I am trying to do this in Racket.

This is what I have got so far, I don't know how to move ahead. Would I need to use mutable variables?

```
(define (list-range a b)
(local [(define sum a)]
 (build-list (+ (- a b) 1)
             lambda (x y) 
             [(<= sum b)(+ sum 1)]
             ))
```

Please help me understand and solve this

Answer (score 1):

This builds a list from `from` inclusive to `to` exclusive.
The inclusive/exclusive thing is the convention in Racket.
It is simply the most convenient due to the fact that list
indices start from 0.

```
#lang racket
(define (list-range from to)
  (build-list (- to from)
              (lambda (i) (+ from i))))

(list-range 5 7)
```

Output:
    '(5 6)